# Dónde puedo descargar de manera confiable pythoncom, pyHook, pyWin32, y pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear mi primer Keylogger pero no puedo descargar estos elementos.
Además no los puedo encontrar para python 3.6.
Te agradezco si puede ayudarme.

Comment: Simplemente usa [pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage) para instalarlos de forma automática. Si te empeñas en buscar las fuentes o los .whl puedes buscarlos en [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (Python Package Index, que es de donde los obtiene `pip`) o en los repositorios oficiales (Github, SourceForge, etc) o webs de cada proyecto y luego instalas con `pip` o `distutils` (ejecutando el `setup.py`). `pythoncom` va con `pyWin32`, solo instala este ultimo.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pywin32

pip install pyinstaller

pip install pyhook
```

pythoncom creo que viene con pywin32.
Si queres instalar la ultima version de pyinstaller usa:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```